# How multi threaded exception is handled in JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, exception

Suppose my JSP page contains 2 threads running at a time. Error page is defined in page to catch exception. If exception is thrown by both the threads at same time then error page will catch and display stack trace of which thraed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one thread, you must have started one. JSP rendering takes place on a single thread, and it's that thread whose stack trace will be shown. The other thread will end up in the `UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

By the way, multi-threaded JSPs are considered bad practice. I don't know what your thread(s) are doing, but your JSP should restrict itself to rendering a model, which shouldn't need multiple threads.